# Is it possible to silent messages about static files in a Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'd like to silent static file logging in a Ruby on Rails project (while in development). I mean this ones:

```
Started GET "/assets/nav_selected_item.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-28 08:33:57 +0000
Served asset /nav_selected_item.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

I really don't care too much about them and they are adding a lot of noise to the logs and making it hard to find the pieces I do care about.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn them all off in production.rb config file with

```
config.log_level = 'warn'
```

but this turns also other debug messages. **OR**

you can implement your own logger skipping all messages starting with "Served":

```
class IgnoringLogger < ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger
  def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
      super(severity, message) unless severity =~ /^Severity/
    end
  end
end

config.active_record.logger = IgnoringLogger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/development_ignored.log", 0)
```